# Auto-create Association Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `Track` model with an integer attribute called `rank`.
I'm updating the rank by specific actions: listens, downloads, purchases, ect. Ex: when a track is downloaded, in the track_controller I use `track.increment!(:rank, by = 60)`

I am thinking of creating an association model `TrackRank` so I can have a timestamp anytime a track's rank is updated (so I can do a rolling 3-week query of a track's rank for filtering and display purposes).

For every time a Tracks rank attr is updated, ***is there a way to auto-create an associated `TrackRank` object?***

The ultimate goal:
***Be able query the top X amount of tracks based on rank count in the last 3 weeks.***

Answer (score 2):

You can add a conditional call back on the update of the track

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ignored associations and stuff
  after_update :create_track_rank, if: :rank_changed?

  # ignored methods

  private
  def create_track_rank
    track_ranks.create(data)
  end
end
```

Comment: One note - you should refactor the code to avoid `increment`, `update_columns` and other methods that skip callbacks.

Comment: how would i do that? if you write a call back and use a method that avoids callbacks i don't think i can help it.

Comment: My comment was addressed to Ryan Rebo, I see he uses `track.increment!(:rank, by = 60)`, the callback will not work in that case.

Comment: ah ok, it kinda sounded like a comment on me, I thought about it for a sec then i was like ok idk what to do, you tell me lol

Comment: I just looked it up, `increment` doesn't call callbacks, but `increment!` with a bang does, so he's fine.

Comment: @dimuch I see what you are saying. Not sure I will use a callback, but if I do, thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0):

You can update it on the controller

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @track.update!
    TrackRank.create(@track)
  end
end
```